# No colour in MOTD

Tags: ssh, terminal, raspberry-pi, colors, motd

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi, and have started playing around with it. After changing my MOTD, (to include colours), the colour codes are coming up as raw-text instead of executing.

**I am connected to my Raspberry Pi via SSH in a Mac Terminal. I also tried directly via the Raspberries command line. How do I allow colour?**

**Below is a screenshot of the failed MOTD:**

[image: MOTD Colour Error]

The file I am editing is "/etc/motd". I am editing it with "nano".

**Code below:**

```
The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.

#!/bin/bash
echo "$(tput setaf 2)
   .~~.   .~~.
  '. \ ' ' / .'$(tput setaf 1)
   .~ .~~~..~.
  : .~.'~'.~. :
 ~ (   ) (   ) ~
( : '~'.~.'~' : )
 ~ .~ (   ) ~. ~
  (  : '~' :  ) $(tput sgr0)Raspberry Pi$(tput setaf 1)
   '~ .~~~. ~'
       '~'
$(tput sgr0)"
```

Comment: motd is a text file read by login. You can't run a script in it.

Comment: Can you paste the code instead of an image? That makes it much easier to help you.

Comment: @fd0 I had a feeling someone would say that... Is there a way I can execute a scripted file upon connection?

Comment: @klimpergeist Exactly the same. Updated for you.

Comment: @FinnRayment A `cron` or `systemd` job should do the trick. There you can execute arbitrary scripts at a given time or on startup.

Comment: @klimpergeist Sorry, as stated, I am horrible with Unix at the moment. :) What should I do with those?

Comment: @FinnRayment Best look at some manuals on the web. But I also posted a simpler solution (hopefully) below as an answer.

Comment: @klimpergeist I found a solution thanks to your help! Thanks. Mind if I edit your answer to reflect the solution?

Comment: @FinnRayment Sure. Go ahead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to the fact that "etc/motd" is a plain text file, commands are not executed, but instead printed as so:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$(tput setaf 2)
   .~~.   .~~.
  '. \ ' ' / .'$(tput setaf 1)
   .~ .~~~..~.
  : .~.'~'.~. :
 ~ (   ) (   ) ~
( : '~'.~.'~' : )
 ~ .~ (   ) ~. ~
  (  : '~' :  ) $(tput sgr0)Raspberry Pi$(tput setaf 1)
   '~ .~~~. ~'
       '~'
$(tput sgr0)"
```

Instead, create a new file called "motd.sh" inside "/etc" and input the MOTD there instead. This is now an executable script, but is not executed. So goto "/etc/profile" and add at the end of the file:

`bash /etc/motd.sh`

This will now execute the script upon connection and display colour.

```
   .~~.   .~~.
  '. \ ' ' / .'
   .~ .~~~..~.
  : .~.'~'.~. :
 ~ (   ) (   ) ~
( : '~'.~.'~' : )
 ~ .~ (   ) ~. ~
  (  : '~' :  ) Raspberry Pi
   '~ .~~~. ~'
       '~'
```