# Why does SSH kill the colour in my /etc/update-motd.d/ script when force_color_prompt=yes is set in ~/.bashrc?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, motd

I have an MOTD script installed in /etc/update-motd.d that works properly, however it seems that SSH bleeds out the colour.

SSHD Look:

[image]

Output when running the script once logged in:

[image]

Actual script:

```
cat /etc/update-motd.d/20-logo 
#! /usr/bin/env bash
echo "";
echo "$(tput setaf 2)    .::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::...
   :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.
   .::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.
                                      .....::::::::::::::::::
                  $(tput setaf 7):@@@@@O                          $(tput setaf 2).:::::::::::
                  $(tput setaf 7)@@@@@@@o                             $(tput setaf 2).::::::::
                  $(tput setaf 7)@@@@@@@o                                $(tput setaf 2):::::::
                  $(tput setaf 7)@@@@@@@o                                $(tput setaf 2).::::::
        $(tput setaf 7):@@@@@O   @@@@@@@o   O@@@@O                       $(tput setaf 2):::::::
      $(tput setaf 7):@@@@@@@@o  @@@@@@@o  o@@@@@@@O                    $(tput setaf 2):::::::.
     $(tput setaf 7)o@@@@@@@@O   @@@@@@@o  :@@@@@@@@@                $(tput setaf 2).::::::::.
    $(tput setaf 7)o@@@@@@@O     @@@@@@@o    o@@@@@@@O        $(tput setaf 2)..:::::::::::::
    $(tput setaf 7)@@@@@@@O      @@@@@@@o     :@@@@@@@o  $(tput setaf 2)::::::::::::::::::
   $(tput setaf 7)o@@@@@@@       @@@@@@@:      o@@@@@@@ $(tput setaf 2)::::::::::::::::.
   $(tput setaf 7)o@@@@@@o        o@@@O:        @@@@@@@ $(tput setaf 2).:::::::::..
   $(tput setaf 7)o@@@@@@@                     o@@@@@@@   $(tput setaf 2).:::::::::
   $(tput setaf 7)o@@@@@@@                     O@@@@@@O     $(tput setaf 2).:::::::::.
    $(tput setaf 7)@@@@@@@@                   O@@@@@@@:       $(tput setaf 2).::::::::::.
     $(tput setaf 7)@@@@@@@@O               :@@@@@@@@o           $(tput setaf 2).:::::::::::.
      $(tput setaf 7)@@@@@@@@@O:          o@@@@@@@@@o               $(tput setaf 2)::::::::::::::.
       $(tput setaf 7)O@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@:                   $(tput setaf 2).:::::::::::::::..
         $(tput setaf 7)O@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@:                         $(tput setaf 2).:::::::::::::::.
           $(tput setaf 7):@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@O                                $(tput setaf 2).::::::::::::
               $(tput setaf 7)oO@@@@@@@@@@o:                                        $(tput setaf 2)..::::.$(tput sgr0)
";
echo "================================================================================";
```

I've ensured that `force_color_prompt=yes` is enabled in `~/.bashrc` and that my `$TERM` variable looks right on both sides. Both terminal-emulator and server show `xterm-256color`

*What could be causing the colour to fail on SSH login?*

Comment: Did you try to use ANSI color codes instead ? Green \u001b[32m as an example.

Comment: No, I will give it a try however that would leave the question as is, because tput should and will work as evidenced by other questions and various howto's on the internet. The tput command outputs the ANSI colour codes. Examples linked. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223921/no-colour-in-motd - https://ownyourbits.com/2017/04/05/customize-your-motd-login-message-in-debian-and-ubuntu/

Comment: ANSI codes do not make a difference, result is the same.

Comment: Gaaaaah! 40 plus processes forked for nothing. What a waste of CPU cycles...

Comment: I've ended up going back and getting ansible to pregen the motd ansi as zeppelin suggested, while storing the original script as is in the source role for readability. So no wasted CPU cycles @Jens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamic MOTD is generated by the `pam_motd` module (/etc/pam.d/login), which uses a piece of code like that to do it:

```
if (!system("/usr/bin/env -i PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin run-parts --lsbsysinit /etc/update-motd.d > /run/motd.dynamic.new"))
rename("/run/motd.dynamic.new", "/run/motd.dynamic");
```

As `env` is invoked with `-i`

-i, --ignore-environment  start with an empty environment

no TERM variable is available by the time `tput` is run, so no color codes are included in the output:

```
%env -i /etc/update-motd.d/20-logoenv -i /etc/update-motd.d/20-logo
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
...
```

As a workaround you can pre-generate your logo with the escape codes embedded into it, like that:

```
%/etc/update-motd.d/20-logo > /tmp/color.logo
%(echo "#! /usr/bin/env bash"; 
  echo "cat <<EOF"; cat /tmp/color.logo; 
  echo "EOF") > /etc/update-motd.d/20-logo
```

or just set an explicit TERM variable at the top of your script:

```
 export TERM=xterm-256color
```

Both options are not perfect (as TERM type will be set fixed by the time MOTD is generated), but AFAIK that is the best you can do (unless you want to patch the `pam_motd` itself).

Comment: Exporting the variable did the trick without need for me to pregenerate anything, which is what I wanted to achieve. Thanks!